# how can i download ubuntu's kernel?

Tags: kernel, compiling, downloads, tar, source

is there any way to find and download latest Ubuntu desktop specific kernel?
for example how can i download latest kernel belongs to Ubuntu 21.10?

i am looking for `.tar.xz` file of Ubuntu kernel.

also, how can i find ubuntu's default `.config` file for kernel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can query them in their packages search list.
https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=linux-image-generic

This is for Ubuntu 21.10: [Package: linux-image-generic (5.13.0.21.32 and others)](https://packages.ubuntu.com/impish/linux-image-generic)

tar.xz:
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-meta/linux-meta_5.13.0.21.32.tar.xz